# 'animation' which uses sleep takes longer with closed IDE than with opened IDE

Tags: excel, vba, ide, sleep

I have, once again, a strange problem with Excel-VBA.. I have a UserForm on which I 'grow' a bar using a label with background color and changing its height in a loop. It looks like this

```
With obj
  Do While Not .highEnough
   .raise
   Sleep 1
   DoEvents
  Loop
End With
```

Everything is working as expected. The only strange thing is: If the IDE is opened or had been opened during the session of excel everything works smoothly. But the moment I start Excel fresh and start my program the animations take more time, an estimated tenfold increase at least.

The load on the processor is no different so it almost seems as if the sleep-command would sleep longer? Does anyone have had the same problem or even knows how to avoid that?

Update/Edit: It's fascinating, today I can not manage to get that same behaviour in the exact same file as yesterday. I definitely can not explain that. I'm using Rubberduck, but closing the application and reopening it should have the same effect as restarting the computer, or not? Or it is a windows problem?

I wrote a testfile, you can download it as [txt-file](https://ufile.io/m1c3t) or [xlsb-file](https://uploadfiles.io/q16uj)  .. I simplified it and most of the comments are german I think, but as I said at the moment I can not manage to provoke that error anymore. Any ideas are appreciated!

EDIT:

Just in case anyone stumbles across my problem. I circumvented it by using my own sleep function. Of course the time is not really accurate but at least it gives me a consistent behaviour.

```
Public Sub Sleep(microseconds As Long)

Dim t0 As Double

t0 = Timer
Do While Timer - t0 <= microseconds / 1000000#: Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] so we can test it?

Comment: Can you put the code into the question please? People here including me don't like files from unkown sources. Also files disapear after a while and the question get's useless.

Comment: You're right, I didn't want to do that either because I have the same suspicions, but it's quite a lot of code. The bars are in their own class with its own functions and there is a little userform, which I cannot 'post'. I wanted to make the example as close to the original as possible because I don't know what causes the error. I can upload the code in a .txt file if that is of any help

Comment: Since you told you use rubberduck: If this is analyzing the project while you run the animation it slows it down (tested it). Animation runs in `0,262s` while rubberduck is analyzing it took me `0,508s`. So I think this depends on what else is running in your Excel environment. Since VBA does not support multi-threading I think it will be hard to get time critical stuff run in real-time.

Comment: But the thing is I saw the opposite behaviour. With rubberduck open the animation is faster. Yesterday when I tested it with rubberduck opened the animation took `0,25s` without it `2,83s`. And as far as I know there is nothing else running in my environment. Procexp shows only a marginal load of `~3%` while the animation is running, both in slow and fast.

Comment: As I said I suspect that such time critical actions will ever work properly in VBA. VBA is completely singe threaded that means if anything in your code stops or gets slowed down by any reason the complete execution waits until it can proceed. Which makes it really hard to get something like a realtime animation.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your time and effort! Then I guess I have to do further inspections to maybe find whats slowing everything down ..